# In a declaration with initialization, can I use a reference to uninitialized data?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, undefined-behavior

I have a function that creates and returns an object. It also has a side-effect, writing a success flag into a boolean variable:

```
struct MyObject
{
    ...
    int field1;
    char field2;
    bool field3;
};

MyObject CreateMyObject(bool& success)
{
    ...
}
```

By pure coincidence it happens that I have to store the success flag in my object. So I can write it in this obvious way:

```
bool success;
MyObject x = CreateMyObject(success);
x.field3 = success;
```

Or in this way:

```
MyObject x = CreateMyObject(x.field3);
```

Does the second way involve undefined behavior, from multiple assignments to `field3` or otherwise?

(My `struct` is not a POD, if that matters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The people who wrote the standard have thought of this case, and the bad news is that it is forbidden:

> #### 12.7 Construction and destruction
>
> 1 - For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior. [...]

There is an example given that is pretty close to your code:

```
struct W { int j; };
struct X : public virtual W { };
struct Y {
  int *p;
  X x;
  Y() : p(&x.j) { // undefined, x is not yet constructed
  }
};
```

In that case, the undefined behaviour is forming a pointer to a member of a not-yet-constructed member; forming a reference to a member is similar enough.

I think it's pretty clear that in order to pass the reference into your constructor, you'd have to take the reference (to the member of the object) *before the constructor begins execution*.

Comment: Is the word _"referring"_ really equivalent to _"taking a reference/pointer to..."_? I have read it as _"dereferencing any reference/pointer to..."_...

Comment: @Massa that would be "*accessing*". The example (which is in the standard) seems pretty clear.