# C+11 Strategy Pattern with state

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11

An example of [**Strategy Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) from the book, [**Head First Design Patterns**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do), was written in C++ at [[**here**]](http://r3dux.org/2011/07/an-example-implementation-of-the-strategy-design-pattern-in-c/). I'm practicing to transform it into C++11 style according to [**Effective GoF Patterns with C++11 and Boost**](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/gof-patterns-c-plus-plus-boost) as showing below.

The **Quack** behavior:

```
struct Quack {
    static void quack()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct MuteQuack {
    static void quack()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The **Fly** behavior:

```
struct FlyWithWings {
public:
    static void fly()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct FlyNoWay {
public:
    static void fly()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The **Duck** hierarchy:

```
class Duck
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(void)> QUACK;
    typedef std::function<void(void)> FLY;

public:
    Duck(const QUACK &q, const FLY &f)
        : m_Quack(q), m_Fly(f) {}

    virtual ~Duck()
    {
    }

    void perform_quack()
    {
        m_Quack();
    }
    void perform_fly()
    {
        m_Fly();
    }

protected:
    QUACK   m_Quack;
    FLY     m_Fly;

private:
    Duck(const Duck&) = delete;
    Duck& operator=(const Duck&) = delete;
};

class MallardDuck
    : public Duck
{
public:
    MallardDuck()
        : Duck(&Quack::quack, &FlyWithWings::fly)
    {
    }
};

class PaintedDuck
    : public Duck
{
public:
    PaintedDuck()
        : Duck(&MuteQuack::quack, &FlyNoWay::fly)
    {
    }
};
```

So far so good, the client works well.

```
int main()
{
    MallardDuck x1;
    x1.perform_quack();
    x1.perform_fly();

    PaintedDuck x2;
    x2.perform_quack();
    x2.perform_fly();

    return 0;
}
```

Now I would like to extend to a new class `RubberDuck` to **Duck** hierarchy, and the `RubberDuck` uses a new fly behavior `FlyWithRocket` which has a object state. As following:

A new **Fly** behavior:

```
class FlyWithRocket {
public:
    FlyWithRocket() : m_Energy(3) {}
    void fly()
    {
        if(m_Energy > 0)
        {
            fly_with_rocket();
            --m_Energy;
        }
        else
        {
            fly_out_of_energy();
        }
    }

private:
    void fly_with_rocket()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    void fly_out_of_energy()
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    unsigned int m_Energy;
};
```

A new **Duck** type:

```
class RubberDuck
    : public Duck
{
public:
    RubberDuck()
        : Duck(&MuteQuack::quack, std::bind(&FlyWithRocket::fly, std::ref(m_flyrocket)))
        , m_flyrocket()
    {
    }
private:
    FlyWithRocket m_flyrocket;
};
```

From now I'm wondering that the rule of the order of member initialization. The base `Duck` initializes before the member `m_flyrocket`, but note that the base `Duck` is initialized with binding `m_flyrocket` which is not initialized yet.
As result as I run it in VS2013, this works without something wrong at run-time.

But is the code actually not safe? If not, how could I modify to a better design?

Comment: The major question is "is passing a non-initialized object to a constructor undefined behavior?". I would guess that in most cases this should work as long as you don't access it during construction, but this answer shows that it is undefined behavior, so not safe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22203006/104774

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not safe, but it's unlikely to break unless you call `m_Fly()` from the base class constructor.

You can easily avoid this though, by either:

1. giving the base class constructor a dummy or default-constructed `std::function`, and re-assigning `m_Fly` to your bind functor in the derived class constructor

   ```
   RubberDuck()
       : Duck(&MuteQuack::quack, std::function<void()>())
   {
       m_Fly = std::bind(&FlyWithRocket::fly, std::ref(m_flyrocket));
   }
   ```
2. making `FlyWithRocket` a functor itself (just rename `void fly` to `void operator()`) and passing it by value instead of keeping a private member (it will be owned by the `m_Fly` function object, and you can access it via `std::function::target<FlyWithRocket>()` if you need)

   ```
   class FlyWithRocket {
   public:
       FlyWithRocket() : m_Energy(3) {}
       void operator() () {
   // ...

   RubberDuck()
       : Duck(&MuteQuack::quack, FlyWithRocket()) {}
   ```